# Date to float from an R Tibble in Python

Tags: python, r, date, tibble

By using an API, I retrieved a Tibble (an R object) in Python (using rpy2.objects), that is a very large 2-dimensional table. It contains a column with dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" when I print the Tibble object. When I grab the Date in Python (simply by indexing the Tibble) it is converted to a 5 digit float. For example, the date "2019-09-28" is converted to the float 18167.0. I'm not sure how to convert it back to a string date (e.g. "YYYY-MM-DD").

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm happy to clarify anything that I can :)

Edit: The answer I discovered with help was the following

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(18167.0,unit='d',origin='1970-01-01')
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide something we can execute on our console, charl1e. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Date` class got converted to `numeric` storage mode, we can use `as.Date` with `origin`

```
as.Date(18167, origin = "1970-01-01")
#[1] "2019-09-28"
```

The `Date` storage mode is `numeric`

```
storage.mode(Sys.Date())
#[1] "double"
```

---

In `python`, we can also do

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
date.fromordinal(int(18167) + date(1970, 1, 1).toordinal()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#'2019-09-28'
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect! But is there an equivalent in Python? Edit: I found it! Thanks!